# How many rectangles are in this image?

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, lateral-thinking

Entering 30 characters is quite a lo

[image]

Comment: Please don't use JPG for non-photographic images.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that

> a pixel counts as a rectangle,

there are

> 14460060000 rectangles. That is the count of various sized rectangles in a grid of 600 x 400 rectangles. For example, there are $1152 = (600-589+1) \times (400-305+1)$ rectangles of size $589 \times 305$.

Comment: I have an LCD, so all my pixels have three(?) subpixels. Wouldn't that change the number?

Comment: @Alexander, this is a logic puzzle, so it's fair to assume we're talking about logical pixels, not physical ones ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I will say that there is:

> 240000 rectangles. The image is 600x400 pixels, and since squares are a kind of rectangle, I'm going to go with that. I'm thinking its going to be more complex than that though.

Updated answer:

> Using a formula I found on a different question, the amount of rectangles found on a grid m wide and n tall is equal to mn(m+1)(n+1)/4. This gives us an answer of 14460060000 rectangles on a 400x600 grid.

Comment: That can’t be it. A group of two or four squares still forms another rectangle

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was thinking. I'm gonna try something

Comment: theres probably a math equation

Comment: Found the equation. In the updated edit

Comment: Squares are indeed kind of like rectangles $-$ but they are not rectangles :)

Comment: edit came just after Bass' answer, correct anyway!

Comment: I know, I accidentally deleted the edit the first time too! Ill get him next time :P

Comment: @user477343 a square is a specialized case of the rectangle, so it's a rectangle too

Comment: @qqjkztd Well in saying that, we could also say that a rectangle is a specialised case of a square. Would that be right? ..... I feel like Adam and Eve when they ate the apple and finally realised they were naked, like my eyes had been closed for a very long time.

Comment: All squares are rectangles, but not all rectangles are squares. So I would argue that a rectangle isn't a specialised case of a square.

Comment: @ShinjiWins well we can apply all the same formulae of a square to a rectangle, and vice versa. Say the rectangle has length $a$ and width $b$ then area is equal to $ab$. And volume is equal to $abc$ if the rectangle had some depth $c$. And surface area of a rectangle in three dimensions would be $2(ab + bc + ac)$. We can apply the same formulae to a square, but for the shape to be a square in the first place, $a = b = c$. It seems like all rectangles can be squares if we just change the sign from being $\neq$ to $=$.

Comment: @ShinjiWins let us have a set $\{a, b, c\}$ given that $a = b = c$ for squares, and a set $\{a, b, c\}$ given that $a\neq b\neq c$ for rectangles. Both sets aren't equal, but they are equivalent, so in one way of looking at it, squares and rectangles are not equal.... but equivalent? They are special cases of each other, I suppose.

Comment: You are right @user477343, but that's the thing with rectangles. You can't just change ≠ to = because that eliminates most instances of a rectangle. A square is a rectangle ALL of the time, whereas a rectangle is a square only SOME of the time.

Comment: sniped dang it. school

Comment: good job m8, I found the equation like 5 minutes late then replied an hour late lol

Comment: @ShinjiWins The game is on, then! (Karma will definitely be on your side though, since just yesterday I happened to snipe an hours-old puzzle by exactly eight seconds..)

Answer (score 3):

Well... I will say...

> Zero? None of the red shapes is a real rectangle. If you focus you can see some orange rectangles flashing inside the red shapes but that is just optical illusions.

With the lateral-thinking tag I have another answer:

> 240 000, the total number of pixels of this image (600x400), a pixel is a square, and a square is a rectangle.

Comment: It's the JPG compression. One should never use JPG for non-photographic images.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is:

> 1 the image itself is a 1 giant white rectangle.

Comment: exactly what i thought

Answer (score 2):

Combining both the answer from Shinji Wins & Mhmd, one might conclude:

> It has 240001, 240000 for the amount of pixels and one for the entire picture

Answer (score 1):

There are as many rectangles as the meaning of the question will allow. So the answer is anything between 1 (the whole image) and infinity (if we allow the set of all possible rectangles which could be fitted in the bounding rectangle).